# The equations $a^x=\log_ax$

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

> How many solutions does equation
>   $$a^x=\log_ax$$

1) Let $a>1$

For example: $a=2$

There are no solutions 
[image]

2) Let $0<a<1$

For example: $a=\frac12$

There are one solution here.

[image]

#### But if $a=1,1$ then

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation looks absolutely awful in this form, but the symmetry and the images actually help you find a way of transforming the equation differently. You know the solutions will always lie on the diagonal $y=x$, so instead of solving your equation, you can just solve

$$a^x=x$$

This is a transcendental equation, but is in a very well known form. Equations which have exponentials and polynomials at the same time, can sometimes be reduced to the Lambert W function: a transcendental function that is defined as the solution of the equation $x e^x=y$ as such: $x=W(y)$.

To get this form, turn it around:

$$1=x a^{-x}= x e^{-x \ln a}$$
Now use a new variable $u=-x \ln a$, and you get

$$-\ln a = u e^u$$
which has a solution
$$ u= W(-\ln a)$$
How is this useful? We know, that this will have a solution, when $W$ has a solution. $W(y)$ has two solutions, when $-1/e<y<0$, and one solution for $y>0$. It has no solutions for $y<-1/e$.

From this, you can get the ranges for $a$.

The midpoint between $1$ solution and $2$ solutions is $-\ln a =0$, which corresponds to $a=1$ (this is the midpoint between rising exponentials, which intersect the diagonal twice, and falling exponentials which have just 1 intersection). The critical point where it gets to no solutions at all, is at

$$-\ln a = -1/e\rightarrow a=e^{1/e}\approx 1.44466786$$

The final answer is therefore:

- 1 solution if $0<a\leq 1$
- 2 solutions if $1<a<e^{1/e}$
- 1 double solution (touching curves) if $a=e^{1/e}$
- no solutions for $a>e^{1/e}$

Comment: I think case $a=1$ should be excluded as $log$ is not defined in that case

Comment: Sure, it's a singular case, the original equation is undefined ther. I just included it, because $1^x$ does exist, and graphically speaking, its inverse is a vertical line, even though it's not a function and not expressible explicitly over $x$.

Answer (score 2):

You can instead solve $x=\log_ax$, because $a^x$ and $\log_ax$ are inverse function to one another.

Since $\log_ax=\frac{\log x}{\log a}$ (natural logarithm), we can as well consider $x\log a=\log x$. Consider
$$
f(x)=x\log a-\log x
$$
over $(0,\infty)$; then $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty$ and
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=
\begin{cases}
-\infty & 0<a<1 \\[4px]
\infty & a>1
\end{cases}
$$
Moreover
$$
f'(x)=\log a-\frac{1}{x}
$$
For $0<a<1$ the derivative is everywhere negative and the equation $x=\log_ax$ has a single solution.

For $a>1$, the function is decreasing over $(0,1/\log a]$ and increasing over $[1/\log a,\infty)$. The minimum value is
$$
f(1/\log a)=1+\log\log a
$$
which is negative if and only if $\log\log a<-1$, that is, $\log a<e^{-1}$ and so $a<e^{1/e}\approx1.444667861$.

The equation has

- one solution for $0<a<1$ (the function $f$ is decreasing)
- two solutions for $1<a<e^{1/e}$ (the function $f$ has negative minimum)
- one solution for $a=e^{1/e}$ (the function $f$ has minimum $0$)
- no solution for $a>e^{1/e}$ (the function $f$ has positive minimum)

Answer (score 0):

some corrections:

for example:

a=0.027

[image]

three solutions.

---

| a | number | tangent line |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $a>\sqrt[e]{e}$ | 0 |  |
| $a=\sqrt[e]{e}$ | 1 | $y=x$ |
| $1 < a <\sqrt[e]{e}$ | 2 |  |
| $ \dfrac 1{e^e}< a < 1$ | 1 |  |
| $ a=\dfrac 1{e^e} $ | 1 | $y=\dfrac 2e-x$ |
| $0< a <\dfrac 1{e^e}$ | 3 |  |

link: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/rqg75ze2